# Zend decorator - Add css class on field element?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am trying to use a zend decorator to use custom containers and add css classes on my elements.

```php
$form->setElementDecorators(array(
    'viewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('Label'),
    array(
        array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),
        array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'col-md-6')
    )
));
$form->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array(
        array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),
        array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'row')
    ),
    'Form'
));
```

Is there a way to add a css class directly on my inputs? `<input class="form-control">`

Is there a way to encapsulate label and input in 2 divs?

Actually i have is

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label></label>
    <input>
</div>
```

and what i wish is

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also where can i found documentation about array to pass to setElementDecorators() function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `HtmlTag` decorator like this:

```
$form->setElementDecorators(array(
    'viewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('Label'),
    array(
        array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),
        array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'form-group'),        
    ),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'col-md-6')),
));
```

For all elements, you can add a class like this:

Example to **set** `form-control` class:

```
foreach($form->getElements() as $element){
    $element->setAttrib('class', 'form-control');
}
```

Example to **add** `form-control` class:

```
foreach($form->getElements() as $element){
    $element->setAttrib('class', 'form-control' . ($element->getAttrib('class') == '' ? '' :  ' ' . $element->getAttrib('class')));
}
```

Comment: Oups... sorry, my "what i wish" html code wasn't correct. I just update it.